# python　floatに変換できない文字列データのエラーに関して

Tags: python

お世話になります。求人案件の年収予測を行う過程で
学習⇒パラメーター調整の段階で躓いてしまったので質問させていただきます。

このような特徴量を生成しており、[image: 特徴量]

学習後ランダムフォレストで下記のようにパラメーター調整したところ

```py
X = train_data[feature_cols]
y = train_data[target_col]
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1234)

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1234)
params = {"n_estimators": [700, 720,  740, 760 ,  780,  800], "max_depth": [3, 4, 5,6,7]}
gscv = GridSearchCV(rf, param_grid=params, verbose=1, cv=3,
                    scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', n_jobs=-1)
gscv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

[image: エラー内容]

となり、floatに変換できない文字列データが「c1070dcb」という'company id'のどれが該当するのか
確認したのですがそれらしいものはなく、どう対処すればよいか分からずお伺いさせていただきました。

[image: 該当データ列]

全てダミー変数化できているはずなのでcompany_idそのものに問題があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 項目名が`ID`なので`float`にする意味があるのか疑問ですが、8桁の16進数文字列のようなので一旦`int`を経由すれば間接的に`float`にすることは可能では？ [convert pandas dataframe column from hex string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37955856/9014308) どうにかすると`8桁の16進数文字列`を直接`float`に変換できるのかもしれませんが。

Comment: @kunif 様　ご回答いただきありがとうございます。1行目にいただいていた通り項目のIDはfloatにする必要がなかったのでset_indexで再度インデックス化することで学習させることで無事解決いたしました！お騒がせいたしました。

Answer (score 1):

まず company_id が float にできないのはそもそも float になるようなデータでは無いからです。実際生データを見てみるとどれにも `Cd346dca` のような「`C` + 16 進表記の数」という文字列が入っており、これは小数では無く float にはできません。

そもそもこのデータは名前の通り ID で、つまりその行の名前のようなものです。機械学習に使うのであれば特徴量として使うには不適切な値でしょう。単にこの列を使わないようにすれば良さそうです。あるいは、お使いのライブラリによっては特定の列を行名を表す列（インデックス列）として扱える方法があるので、それを使っても良いでしょう。